# Assigning patch values as a list variable using raster/.csv data

Tags: r, csv, gis, netlogo, raster

I'm working on this as part of my PhD and I'm really stuck with it.

I'm using NetLogo to build an spatially explicit ABM and I need to set a variable as a list containing 500 values for each patch.

The values come from a RasterStack object created in R, where the RasterStack has 500 layers. I'm familiar with the NetLogo gis extension and know about gis:load-dataset and gis:apply-raster primitives. As far as I'm aware though, NetLogo doesn't support RasterStacks and it would be hugely inefficient to load 500 individual raster files.

My other approach was to utilise the Csv extension. I converted my RasterStack into a csv with xy coordinates, row and column information, and then 500 columns with each value. However i'm struggling to reference the rows and columns in the .csv with pxcor and pycor in NetLogo.

I've included below R code that generates a RasterStack of 5 layers, and the data.frame that would be exported as .csv

```
library(raster)

    xmin <- 375100
    ymin <- 818200
    xmax <- 379600
    ymax <- 823200

e <- extent(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)

set.seed(678)
r <- raster(nrow=250, ncol=225, ext = e, res = 20)
s1 <- setValues(r,runif(n = ncell(r), min = 0, max=5))
s2 <- setValues(r,runif(n = ncell(r), min = 0, max=5))
s3 <- setValues(r,runif(n = ncell(r), min = 0, max=5))
s4 <- setValues(r,runif(n = ncell(r), min = 0, max=5))
s5 <- setValues(r,runif(n = ncell(r), min = 0, max=5))

s <- stack(s1,s2,s3,s4,s5) # Raster Stack

df <- stack %>% as.data.frame(xy = TRUE)
cols <- colFromX(stack, df$x)
rows <- rowFromY(stack, df$y)

patches <- df %>% mutate(col = cols, row = rows) # For export as .csv
```

I don't have NetLogo code worth showing as I'm completely stumped! To clarify, the end product i'm looking for is a NetLogo world based on spatially explicit raster/csv data, where each patch has a list of values for a variable.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe the "File Input Example" from the Models Library is helpful for you. It loads in patch data from a txt file. You can probably adapt it to reading csv files.

Comment: Thanks Lena this was really helpful. I managed to get my patch data in a .csv file and was then able to add a column that contained a list of values for each patch.